# Executing functions from Loaded Module is locking or non blocking?

Tags: python, module

Below is the pseudo code which makes use of imp python library to load module. It loads the module and then invokes executes the `execute()` function in the module.

Below is the pseudo code.

```
for path in loader_file:
    mod = imp.load(load_module,path)
    result = mod.execute()
```

`mod.execute()` will be a blocking call or non-bocking call? 
i.e.

- Once the first module finishes and gets the result then the next module will be loaded.
- Or the `mod.execute()` will get called and before it finishes the next module will get loaded.

Comment: I'm guessing that will depend on if you defined `execute(..)` as an `async` function..

Comment: can you please elaborate bit more

Comment: If you write it to be non-blocking (ie. asynchronous), then it will be non-blocking; otherwise it will block (ie. be synchronous). Googling "async function python" should give you pointers in case you are unfamiliar with async functions in python...